# Avg-min-max chart in plotly

Tags: plot, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm building a screener using plotly dash based on some plots generated through Microsoft Excel. One of those charts is the Avg-max-min, below an example of this type of graph.

[image: ly]

I have no idea on how to "translate" this kind of graph in to a plotly figure, I've tried this so far, but I did not succeed:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
        x=[0, 1, 2],
        y=[6, 10, 2],
        error_y=dict(
            type='data', # value of error bar given in data coordinates
            array=[1, 2, 3],
            visible=True)
    ))
```

I think I've got really close to the real solution, is basically doing a errorbar plot without lines.

Comment: Do you mind to add a sample of your df?

Comment: @Occhima If the provided suggestion was helpful, plase upvote and consider to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @vestland i've thought that i've already done that, ty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me that there is a prebuilt function to do so unless you are happy with [box plots](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/).

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_obj as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
                   "y":[1,2,4, 1, 10, 4]})

# here I calculate min, max and mean for every x
grp = df.groupby("x").agg({"y":{"min", "max", "mean"}})
grp.columns =  ["_".join(col) for col in grp.columns]
grp = grp.reset_index()
```

## Plot

```py
fig = go.Figure()
# first I add a trace for every x
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=grp["x"],
                         y=grp["y_min"],
                         mode="markers",
                         showlegend=False,
                         marker=dict(color="blue",
                                     size=10)))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=grp["x"],
                         y=grp["y_mean"],
                         mode="markers",
                         showlegend=False,
                         marker=dict(color="blue",
                                     size=20)))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=grp["x"],
                         y=grp["y_max"],
                         mode="markers",
                         showlegend=False,
                         marker=dict(color="blue",
                                     size=10)))
# then I add a vertical line for 
# every x where y_min!=y_max
for i, row in grp.iterrows():
    if row["y_min"]!=row["y_max"]:
        fig.add_shape(
            dict(type="line",
                 x0=row["x"],
                 x1=row["x"],
                 y0=row["y_min"],
                 y1=row["y_max"],
                 line=dict(
                   color="blue",
                   width=2)
                )
        )
fig.update_layout(title="Avg-Max-Min Graph", title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

[image]